# How to prevent invalid column name error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table in SSMS:

```
CREATE TABLE Residents
(id_Resident int not null,
Name varchar null,
Surname varchar null,
Adress varchar null,
Date_of_Birth date null,
Criminal_ Record varchar null,
primary key (id_Resident)
);
```

Whenever I run this insert:

```
INSERT INTO Residents (idResident , Name , Surname, Adress , "Date_of_birth" , Criminal_Record)
VALUES ( '0001', 'Filip', 'Krivý', 'Sladkovičova 55', '12.1.1970', 'N/A'),
 ( '0002', 'Jozef', 'Vražel', 'Holého 21', '4.4.1956','3.3.2021' ),
 ( '0003', 'Drahomíra', 'Hofríková', 'Okružná 54', '4.5.1975' , '12.1.2019'),
 ( '0004', 'Ivana', 'Čarnecká', 'Jašíková 11', '16.6.1995' , '6.5.2020'),


SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Invalid column name 'Date_of_birth'.
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Invalid column name 'Date_of_birth'.

Do you know how can I solve this error?

I tried to put use brackets also to prevent this error but it didn't work.

Comment: Why is `Date_of_birth` in quotes? That shouldn't be reserved, and all characters appear to be standard.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b907dc644ec82ca5d5e2cd4659c72cf -- None of your statements are syntactically correct, so you won't even come so far to get the error you claim you get... I.e. your statements don't qualify as [example].

Comment: Might as well pile on this: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a case-sensitive collation,

```
Date_of_birth <> Date_of_Birth
--------^        --------^
```

*Always* match the casing in `sys.columns`.